# show current date and time in a webpage

Tags: php, html

I have a code that shows time and date to my page  but the problem is its not showing the exact data and time in my country.I'm from Philippines can anyone help me?Please.

current code:

```
<label><?php echo date("D M d, Y G:i a"); ?></label>
```

I need to show the current time and date of the Philippines in my webpage.

Comment: What does it show at the moment? Where is your web server located?

Comment: is it has to be on server side? you can get it also with javascript in client side.. then it will be relevant to each client local

Comment: Where is your webserver?

Comment: You have to set your locales accordingly. Preferable in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');?> 

<label><?php echo date("D M d, Y G:i a"); ?></label>
```

Or use datetime object

```
    <?php 
 $datetime = new DateTime; // current time = server time
 $otherTZ  = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Manila');
 $datetime->setTimezone($otherTZ); // calculates with new TZ now

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
<?php 
   date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');// set timezone for Philippines (it is Asia/Manila )
   $date= date('m-d-Y') ;
?>      
 <label><?php echo $date ?></label>
```

OR for Philippines  also you can set timezone in this way:

```
 date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT+8');
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `php.ini` file, look for the line `date.timezone=`. Set this to your current timezone (i.e. `Asia/Manila`). This prevents having to use `date_default_timezone_set()` all the time, which is easy to forget.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
$date = date("D M d, Y G:i a");
<label><?=$date;?></label>
?>
```

or

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');
echo '<label>' . date("D M d, Y G:i a") . '</label>';
?>
```